# Desinging Test Cases using configurable Commandlines.

Tags: testing

I currently working with embedded linux with bash shell on it. Write now I am working on a test framework for that system. The way it works now I have 3 linux commands lines (ie 3 linux programs in C) that execute a paticular test.

ie

```
command1 arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
command2 arg3 arg4 arg5 ...
command3 arg6 arg6 arg7 ...
```

The thing is that the test case combinations are huge. So assume if I have different databases that hold parameters for the 3 command lines. How could I make it so I can generate different combination from the database with out iterating using for loops.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you asking?

How to create test permutations from a data set?  How to query the database for a representative sampling of test data?  How to invoke the test data from your automated tests?  Something else entirely???

Anyway, here's a good link on test permutations:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163513.aspx

'Hope that helps...